# Docker-compose ''NoneType' is not iterable'

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, ubuntu-14.04, docker-compose

I'm trying to run Elasticsearch-Logstash-Kibana stack on docker with configuration from [here](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk). It works fine on Windows, but looks like on my semi-production Ubuntu VM, docker-compose has a problem. When I'm running `docker-compose up`, I'm getting following error:

```
/opt/elk-stack# docker-compose up
Recreating f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_elkstack_elasticsearch_1 ...
Recreating f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_elkstack_elasticsearch_1

ERROR: for f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_f5a2cff82dbf_elkstack_elasticsearch_1  argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

ERROR: for elasticsearch  argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 68, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 118, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 928, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 450, in up
  File "compose/parallel.py", line 70, in parallel_execute
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I tried to remove almost everything from docker-compose.yml file. Here is how it looks now:

```
version: '2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build: elasticsearch/

  logstash:
    build: logstash/
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build: kibana/
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

Unfortunately, the error still persists. When I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml config` it looks like everything was parsed fine, and there is no error in YML file itself:

```
/opt/elk-stack# docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml config
services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: /opt/elk-stack/elasticsearch
  kibana:
    build:
      context: /opt/elk-stack/kibana
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
  logstash:
    build:
      context: /opt/elk-stack/logstash
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
version: '2.0'
```

I've tried different versions of docker-compose, from `1.11.2` to `1.15.0`.
My docker version is `Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5`.
OS is `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`.
The default Python interpreter is `Python 2.7.6`.

I'm giving up - any advices how to make this work?

Comment: No spaces and tabs mixed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version '2.0' of docker-compose, you will need Docker 1.10.0+ as stated in the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#compose-and-docker-compatibility-matrix). Its also stated in the [README](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) of the repo you referred to.

Comment: That was it. After docker-engine update everything is working fine. Too bad there was no way to figure it out from the error message.

Comment: Hint: There are various installation guides out there... I stumbled upon some faulty ones, which lead me to this issue. Use the official ones to prevent issues: https://www.docker.com/community-edition#/download